# Is an HTTP redirect considered as a RELATED connection by iptables?

Tags: iptables, firewall, http

I've been reading about states in iptables.

[This page](http://www.iptables.info/en/connection-state.html#USERLANDSTATES) says

> A connection is considered RELATED when it is related to another already ESTABLISHED connection. What this means, is that for a connection to be considered as RELATED, we must first have a connection that is considered ESTABLISHED. The ESTABLISHED connection will then spawn a connection outside of the main connection. The newly spawned connection will then be considered RELATED, if the conntrack module is able to understand that it is RELATED.

Supposing a httpd connection is allowed by iptables on tcp port A (eg http://www.example.com:8001).  The response from the webserver is a 302 redirect instructing the browser to go to a URL on tcp port B on the same server (eg http://www.example.com:8002).

Is iptables 'aware' of this relationship, and treat packets on the new connection with state RELATED.  Or does iptables consider it a new connection and treat the packets with state NEW?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. the http `REDIRECT` indicates the client that the searched page is now at an other address (maybe in the same host, maybe not).

iptables `RELATED` indicates related connections (usually in parallel, or as reply), and not a new initiated connection.